# How to use a value from one foreach loop in the second one?

Tags: php, foreach

I would like to know how to the following: I have 2 foreach loops, one inside the other.
For example:

```
foreach($a as $b) { 
    foreach($c as $d) { 
        echo $b; 
    }
}
```

Now this code snippet doesnt make any sense, but what I would like to know is how to get the value of the first foreach loop (here the `$b`) into the second foreach loop. Because in this example the `$b` would not be outputted.

So how can I kind of set the variable `$b` as global in order to use it in the second foreach loop?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that example. The problem is elsewhere. Is `$a` actually what you think it is?

Comment: I´ll show you the real problem:

´foreach($_POST["daylist"] as $daylist_id)
 {
  $i = 1;
  
  foreach($_POST["list"] as $list_id)
  {´

Now in the second foreach loop I can not use $daylist_id.

Comment: Ok, the problem is that either `$_POST["daylist"]` or `$_POST["list"]` is empty. Try `print_r( $_POST )` and verify that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's already accessible.

```
foreach($a as $b) { 
    foreach($c as $d) { 
        echo $b; //  $b can be accessed
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do that, `$b` will be accessible in the inner loop by default.

Answer (score 0):

Learn something about scoping
http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

As you will read, it's already accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Check first whether or not you loops run correctly...start with the outer one, than check the inner one...if that is all ok, you must be able to succesfully print a variable from the outer loop scope.

Answer (score 0):

`$b` is accessed as many time as you inner loop 'loops'.